# Forwarding ZNC from domain.com:port to subdomain.domain.com while using SSL and NGINX

Tags: php, ssl, cookies, nginx, proxy

I'm not sure who/how to correctly ask this. I've tried searching and either my Google-fu needs work or I'm just not searching the right terms.  I'm still learning NGINX configs.

Here's my setup:
NGINX, PHP5-FPM
Running ZNC with SSL at domain.com:65000

My current sites-available config:

```
upstream znc-upstream {
        server znc.domain.com:65000;
}

server {

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name znc.domain.com;

        location / {

                proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

                proxy_pass https://znc-upstream;
}
```

It seems to forward fine.  I type znc.domain.com and it forwards to the webadmin login.  However when I enter my username/password, it says cookies aren't enabled, although it shows me logged in with the server's address.

I assume what's happening is that the cookie is being set with the server's address instead of my address once it's forwarded, and since ZNC is configured to only run one session per user at a time, I cannot easily kill the session because it's locked to the local address.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I set up an SSH tunnel to the site and can access it fine with https://localhost:65000.  I cannot access it via znc.domain.com even through the tunnel -- still says "invalid login" and "cookies not enabled."

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well.